# orthogonal projection with $2x=2y=-z$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

English is not my first language, but i hope you can understand.

In orthogonal projection on the line $2x = 2y =-z$ $, (x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})$ ends up on $(y_{1},y_{2},y_{3})$. How to determine a matrix relationship between $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})$ and $(y_{1},y_{2},y_{3})$?

The answer is:$$
\begin{pmatrix}
y_{1}\\ 
y_{2}\\ 
y_{3}
\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{6}\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1  &-2 \\ 
 1&1  &-2 \\ 
 -2&-2  &4 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}\\ 
x_{2}\\ 
x_{3}
\end{pmatrix}$$

I've done:
$$2x = 2y =-z\Rightarrow t(1,1,-2),\ if\ x=t$$

$$\frac{(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})\cdot (1,1,-2)}{(1,1,-2)\cdot (1,1,-2)}(1,1,-2)=\frac{(x_{1}+x_{2}-2x_{3})}{6}(1,1,-2)=\frac{1}{6}(-2x_{2}+2x_{3},-2x_{3}+2x_{1},x_{1}-x_{2})$$

What have i done wrong and how do i proceed?

EDIT 1: Updated the answer and what i've done.

EDIT 2: See below.

$$\frac{(x_{1}+x_{2}-2x_{3})}{6}(1,1,-2)=\frac{1}{6}(x_{1}+x_{2}-2x_{3})(1,1,-2)
$$

If a take $(1,1,-2)$ and put it into $\frac{1}{6}(x_{1}+x_{2}-2x_{3})$, i end up with:$
\frac{1}{6}\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1  &-2 \\ 
 1&1  &-2 \\ 
 -2&-2  &4 
\end{pmatrix}
$.
Can i do this?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  The "projection of 2x= 2y= 2z" onto **what** subspace of $R^3%$?   Also you write the independent variable as $(x, y, z)$ but then have both $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and $(y_1, y_2, y_3)$.

Comment: Your problem is that you divided by $6$ instead of $\sqrt{6}$ (the norm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT1 is incorrect. EDIT2 is right.

$\frac{(x_{1}+x_{2}-2x_{3})}{6}(1,1,-2)$

$=\frac{1}{6}(x_{1}+x_{2}-2x_{3})(1,1,-2)$

Or, $\, = \frac{1}{6}(x_{1}+x_{2}-2x_{3}, \,x_{1}+x_{2}-2x_{3}, -2x_{1}-2x_{2}+4x_{3})$

Or, $ \, = \frac{1}{6}\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1  &-2 \\ 
 1&1  &-2 \\ 
 -2&-2  &4 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}\\ 
x_{2}\\ 
x_{3}
\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general method that you can apply for any kind of orthogonal projection in any $S=\mathbb{R^n}$ onto any subspace $T$ of dimension $p$ (here of course $n=3, p=1$).

Take any orthogonal and normalized (meaning unit norm) basis $V_1,V_2,\cdots V_p$ of $T$.

Let $B=[V_1|V_2| \cdots |V_p]$ the $n \times p$ corresponding matrix of their coordinates.

Then the orthogonal projection matrix is $P=BB^T.$

Here it will be

$$P=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\begin{pmatrix} \ \ 1\\ \ \ 1\\-2\end{pmatrix}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\begin{pmatrix}1&1&-2\end{pmatrix}$$

proving that your last matrix is exact.